# cuda matrix inverse using gauss jordan elimination

Tags: c, matrix, cuda

I'm trying to find matrix inverse using gauss jordan elimination in cuda and here is my kernel code to convert a given n*n matrix to diagonal matrix:

```
__global__ void gaussjordan(float *A,  float *I,int n)
{
    int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    float P;

        if(x!=y)
        {
            P=A[x*n+y]/A[y*n+y];
            for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
                I[x*n+k]-=I[y*n+k]*P;
                A[x*n+k]=A[x*n+k]-A[y*n+k]*P;
                }
             __syncthreads();
        }
}
```

the problem here is the matrix A[] is not getting updated with the modified values and the threads are taking the initial values.

for example if n=3 consider A[n*n]=[1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3] so after thread iterations  x=1;y=0 and x=2;y=0 A[] becomes [1 2 2 0 -2 -2 0 -2 -1] so for the next thread iterations x=0;y=1 and x=2;y=1 the threads should use the modified A[] values but instead the threads are using the original A values. can anyone help me figure out how to update the vales so the threads can use modified values.

Comment: If your matrices are relatively small, I would suggest downloading NVIDIA's source code (BSD license) for batched matrix inversion from the registered CUDA developer website (login at htpp://developer.nvidia.com). I think the packaged is called "Batched Solver". The matrix inversion code uses Gauss-Jordan.

Comment: no i need to use the code for relatively large matrices. I just used a 3*3 matrix for better understanding